# Are cached plans query shared by all members of a replica set

Tags: mongodb

Are cached plans query shared by all members of a replica set? So if at some point an election takes place, if the secondary (now primary) had never executed the query before, does it have access to plans that were cached by the previous primary?

Comment: Looks unlikely, from the docs > _The plan cache does not persist if a mongod restarts or shuts down._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Nodes in a replica set do not share operational data with each other (e.g. query plan, caches, client connections, etc.). They do ping each other and know which is the primary node, and arrange an election when a primary is not detected in the set.

There are two things that are shared between all data-bearing members of a replica set:

1. The [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which is a log of data manipulation operations (inserts, deletes, user creation, user deletion, collection creation, etc.), but they apply the oplog into their own dataset individually.
2. Replica set configuration (members, protocol version, per-node setting etc.), which is the output of the `rs.conf()` command.

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks @Kevin